# Using function of an already loaded script

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML-page I'm loading a JS-file (main.js) with some functions.

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Navigation</header>
    <main>
        <div id="click_me">
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

**main.js:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    start()
});

function start() {
    $.getScript( 'first.js' ).done(function () { 
        console.log("loaded");
    });
}

function anything() {
    console.log("done");
}
```

Now I'm using $.getScript to load another JS-file (first.js). But this file need to use some functions of the first one.

**first.js:**

```
$('#click_me').on('click', function() {
    anything();
});
```

In this example clicking on the `#click_me` should result in printing "done" in the console.

Comment: Either first.js is missing or you're referring to it as second.js in your example. Anyway, I would add a .fail() handling to account for errors and see if it correctly loads. Couldn't it be a path error?

Comment: How are you including second.js? include that in your question.

Comment: sorry. my mistake. I mean first.js

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. I would add a `.fail()` statement to account for errors as stated by jQuery $.getScript official docs:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

(see **Handling Errors**)

Check for the error marks in console and/or `exception` var to see if there is something wrong while loading the file (mostly expecting a path or syntax error).